# Cucumber Feature Files and scenarios for parallel execution

Tags: cucumber

Using Cucumber we create different feature files that consist of different scenarios. One thing that we keep in mind is that every scenario is independent of all other scenarios.

Question: Can we do parallel execution for all of the feature file or scenarios?

Comment: Please share what flavor of Cucumber you are using. There are different solutions for different environments.

Comment: @ThomasSundberg.. Well I am using java for coding . What else do you mean by flavor? Please elaborate.

Comment: My question is are you using Cucumber-JVM, Cucumber for Ruby or Cucumber for any other language? There are some 10 different implementations to choose from.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSundberg.. Well I am using Cucumber-JVM

Answer (score 1):

out of the box Cucumber doesn't support parallel testing. You can use Maven to run parallel test. We have a github project check this link. It has some details on parallel testing.

check out these links:

1. [JVM-Parallel Execution Example](https://opencredo.com/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/)
2. [Git-Hub Link](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as the two other answers suggest, it is not out of the box.

- For Cucumber-JVM (java) use [this Maven plugin](https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin).
- For ruby Cucumber use [this ruby gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests).

I work for the company that hosts that Cucumber-JVM post above. Acceptance tests - especially web based ones - are often really slow, and parallel testing is a great way to speed them up. You may also want to consider running web tests in headless browser, such as phantomJS. They're great for overnight runs, but I'd test it on firefox or chrome before releasing. You may have browser specific bugs.

If you're running Selenium tests, you might want to consider also using Selenium Grid. The above methods launch multiple browsers on the same machine - but machines can only run so many browsers. Selenium Grid will balance tests across a number of machines. So you could have, for example, 5 nodes running 5 parallel tests each = 25 tests in parallel!

If running many tests in parallel, remember that tests should be isolated - and ideally have and tear down their own data. Don't assume anything about the order of any other tests ([we use aliasing to get around this](https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-data-aliases/)).

Oh, and if you turn it up *really* high, you'll end up getting a performance test. So be wary of that!

Here's some handy links:

- [Dupe answer about Cucumber JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191296/how-to-run-features-scenarios-in-cucumber-jvm-in-parallel)
- [Test automation quickstart framework for Cucumber JVM - incl parallel -tests](https://github.com/opencredo/test-automation-quickstart)
- [Test automation quickstart framework for Ruby - incl parallel tests and phantomjs integration](https://github.com/opencredo/ruby-acceptance-testing-quickstart)
- [Updated version of the above blog post about parallel cucumber-jvm](https://opencredo.com/test-automation-concepts-parallel-test-execution/)
- [Selenium grid parallel testing intro](https://www.infoq.com/news/2007/09/selenium-grid-parallel-testing)
- [Another question about headless testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone for Help!! I have got the answer. Below is step-wise solution
Flavor - Cucumber-JVM
IDE - Eclipse
1- What?-Remove Your Test Runner File 
   Why? -For parallel testing, JVM automatically creates each runner for each parallel process
   When?-This *Might* be the first step before any config[image]

2- What?-Add Below mentioned properties in your POM.xml
   Why? -*Will add this later*
   When?-Before compiling

[image: UTF-8]

3- What?-Add Below mentioned plugins in your POM.xml
   Why? -This will automatically create runner
   When?-Before compiling

> org.apache.maven.plugins
>                 maven-surefire-plugin
>                 2.19.1
>
> ```
>           <configuration>
>               <additionalClasspathElements>
>                   <additionalClasspathElement>resources</additionalClasspathElement>
>               </additionalClasspathElements>
>               <forkCount>5</forkCount>
>               <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
>               <includes>
>                   <include>**/*IT.class</include>
>               </includes>
>           </configuration>
> ```

[image: ParllelExecution]

4- What?-Add Below mentioned plugins in your POM.xml
   Why? -This will create parallel execution on basis of FEATURE or SCENARIO and 
         will create jason,HTML report as well
   When?-Before compiling

> com.github.temyers
>                 cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin
>                 2.2.0
>                 
>                     
>                         generateRunners
>                         validate
>                         
>                             generateRunners
>
> ```
>                   <configuration>
>                       <glue>russel.StepDefination.Option1.IN451</glue>
>                       <featuresDirectory>Login</featuresDirectory>
>                       <cucumberOutputDir>target/Parallel-report</cucumberOutputDir>
>                       <format>json,html</format>
>                       <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
>                       <!-- <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme> -->
>
>                   </configuration>
>               </execution>
>           </executions>
> ```
>
> [image: ParallelExecutionSceanrio-Feature]

5- Goto Console of and run commomd 
   - mvn clean
   - mvn compile
   - mvn verify

Comment: Good explanation Mirzab, I followed all the steps But Cucumber Output directory "Parallel-report" is not created under "target" folder. Can you please share your complete pom.xml for reference ?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible.

See this link for all the information and credits: http://shashikantjagtap.net/running-cucumber-features-in-parallel-and-aggregating-reports/

Hope this helps